# Function gets defined although code block is not executed

Tags: javascript

I use the following code to use [JS Gettext](http://jsgettext.berlios.de/) if the language is German.

```
if (lang == "de") {
    var gt = new Gettext({"domain": "tag_cloud", "locale_data": json_de_data});
    function _(ident) {
        console.debug('gt.gettext("'+ident+'")');
        return gt.gettext(ident);
    }
    console.debug("Using Gettext.");
}
else {
    function _(ident) {
        console.debug('return "'+ident+'"');
        return ident;
    }
    console.debug("Using no translation.");
}
```

In Firefox, the console shows:

```
Using Gettext.
gt.gettext("Ubiqitous, but effective.")
```

In every other browser (Chromiun, Opera, IE, rekonq, Safari), I get this:

```
Using Gettext.
return "Ubiqitous, but effective."
```

I tried to remove the `else` block and that worked in all browsers then, just not for English.

So is the latter `_()` defined although the `else` block is not executed? How can I make this work in all browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`function _(ident) {}` function declaration will be evaluated before run-time, which is at the parse-time.

You can change to `var _ = function(ident) {}`, this way `_` will be assigned at run-time.

Get the further reading: [Named function expressions demystified](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/)

Comment: Okay, that is interesting. I guess that is a bug in Firefox's Javascript engine then?

Comment: The first way is browser dependent, so you should use the second way `var _ = function(ident){}`.

Comment: Always use the second way or just on critical functions like this?